# Working with error lists while compiling

Tags: buffers, split

When I try to get a program to compile, I use the following process:

1. `:sh` to open a shell
2. `make`
3. scroll up to see the compilation errors
4. exit to get back to vim
5. fix errors that I remember (usually 2 or 3 of them)
6. goto step 1

This is kind of tedious, ideally I would like to see the errors in a horizontal split pane alongside the code I am editing. However, unlike emacs I cannot open a buffer that has a terminal in it.

How can I improve my process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at [`:h quickfix.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#quickfix.txt).

> Vim has a special mode to speedup the edit-compile-edit cycle.  This is
>   inspired by the quickfix option of the Manx's Aztec C compiler on the Amiga.
>   The idea is to save the error messages from the compiler in a file and use Vim
>   to jump to the errors one by one.  You can examine each problem and fix it,
>   without having to remember all the error messages.

To compile your code use the `:make` command ([`:h :make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#:make))
Then to move between your errors you can use `:cnext` and `:cprevious`.

The doc describes the behavior of `:make`:

1. If vim was built with `+autocmd`, all relevant `QuickFixCmdPre` autocommands are executed.
2. If the `'autowrite'` option is on, write any changed buffers
3. An errorfile name is made from `'makeef'`.  If `'makeef'` doesn't contain `"##"`, and a file with this name already exists, it is deleted.
4. The program given with the `'makeprg'` option is started (default "make") with the optional `[arguments]` and the output is saved in the errorfile (for Unix it is also echoed on the screen).
5. The errorfile is read using `'errorformat'`.
6. If vim was built with `+autocmd`, all relevant `QuickFixCmdPost` autocommands are executed.  See example below.
7. If `[!]` is not given the first error is jumped to.
8. The errorfile is deleted.
9. You can now move through the errors with commands like `:cnext` and `:cprevious`, see above.

You should also have a look at [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27) to define the behavior of `:make`.

Note that Vim must be compiled with `+autocmd` enabled.

---

Some additional commands to navigate the quickfix list are the following:

```
:cnext  Jump to next item
:cprev  Jump to previous item
:cfirst Jump to first item
:clast  Jump to last item
:cnfile Jump to first item in next file
:cpfile Jump to last item in previous file
:cc     N Jump to nth item
:copen  Open the quickfix window
:cclose Close the quickfix window
```

---

You could also be interested in the location-list feature ([`:h location-list`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#location-list)). There can only be one quickfix list whereas there can be several location-list (one by window), thus you can compile two files and switch between them without erasing the location of the errors.

To manipulate the location-list you can use the same commands as the ones used with the quickfix but prefixing them with `l`: `:lmake`, `:lnext`, etc... The commands interacting with the location-list will use the location-list of the current window.

---

I would also recommend reading [Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim) which provides some very good tips and has a section dedicated to compilation and using the quickfix list.